# antiderivative of lebesgue integrable function

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:[0,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue integrable. We define 
$$g(x)=\int_x^b\frac{f(t)}{t}dt,\quad 0<x\le b.$$ Show that $g(x)$ is Lebesgue integrable in $[0,b]$. Also show that 
$$\int_0^bg(x)dx=\int_0^bf(t)dt.$$

If we show the asked equality then it is obvious that $g$ is Lesbegue integrable, since $f$ is.
Now, I have try to show the equality using the fact that, 
$$\int_0^b\Bigl[g'(x)-\frac{f(x)}{x}\Bigr]dx=0$$, since $g$ is the antiderivative of $f$ but I had no success. I am pleased to know other ideas to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Let $\Delta = \{ (x,t) \mid 0 \leq x \leq t \leq b \}$. Define $h(x,t)$ on $[0,b] \times [0,b]$ by $h(x,t) = \chi_{\Delta}(x,t) \frac{f(t)}{t}$. Apply Fubini's theorem to $h$ to integrate it in two different ways. (There will be an initial step involving $|h|$ to prove integrability of $h$.)

Edit: $\Delta$ would more accurately be changed in order to be a subset of $(0,b] \times (0,b]$.

Comment: +1. I would have beaten you to it if I weren't interrupted by a phone call … Let me just add a plug for the Iverson bracket notation: Write $\chi_\Delta(x,t)$ as $[0\le x\le t\le b]$, then $\int_0^b g(x)\,dx=\int\int (f(t)/t)[0\le x\le t\le b]\,dt\,dx$, and the whole calculation becomes much more tractable. (The Iverson bracket was discussed here just a few days ago – search for it.)

Comment: i.e. $I=\int_0^bg(x)dx=\int_0^b\int_0^bh(x,t)dtdx$ and using Fubini I get $I=\int_0^b\int_0^bX_\Delta(x,t)\frac{f(t)}{(t)}dxdt=\int_0^b\frac{f(t)}{t} \int_0^b X_\Delta(x,t)dxdt=\int_0^b\frac{f(t)}{t}tdt=\int_0^bf(t)dt.$ Is this the way to solve it?

Comment: Yes. A similar calculation applied to $|h|$ is first needed to establish that $h$ is integrable and therefore Fubini can be applied to it.

Comment: You're welcome.